# Solution check for counting in a list

Tags: combinatorics

This problem involves lists made from the letters T,H,E,O,R,Y, with repetition allowed.

How many 4-letter lists are there that don’t begin with T, or don’t end in Y ?

Just want to make sure my solution is right and my logic isn't flawed.

My solution:

A = 4 letter lists that don't begin with T

B = 4 letter lists that dont end in Y

$|A| = 5 * 6 * 6 * 6 = 1080$

$|B| = 6 * 6 * 6 * 5 = 1080$

$|A \cup B | = 1080 + 1080 = 2160$

Comment: You have to be careful here as $A \cap B \ne \emptyset$

Comment: looks good to me. The intersection of A and B should not change answers.

Comment: Why is it not $\cup$ since it is OR?

Comment: @Juanito why will the intersection not change the answers? Remember that $|A \cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A\cap B|$

Comment: You are right. I rethought and it seems that there is double accounting, unless the intersection is substracted.

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes, sorry, I've fixed the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation of $|A|$ and $|B|$ are correct, but there are a number of lists that are counted in both of them, so twice in your total of $2160$.  For example, the list $HHHH$ is one of your $1080$ in $A$ and again one of the $1080$ in $B$, so when you try to find $|A \cup B|$ you have counted it twice.

Comment: Can you please explain to me why  I would choose to use an intersection versus union in this question?

Comment: You are trying to find the size of the union.  The equation Mathmo123 gave you shows the correction for the size of the union of two sets that overlap.  The intersection on the right is what you need.

Comment: That's $|A \cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A\cap B|$

Comment: If you think of the two circle Venn diagram, the left circle is $A$, the right circle is $B$ and the overlap is $A \cap B$.  If you add the contents of the two circles, the overlap gets counted twice.  The subtraction of the intersection is to remove the double counting.

Comment: So the correct answer im looking for is 1080? I'm still a bit confused, how would i know the size of the intersection in the case of this question?

Comment: No, it isn't $1080$, either.  You might try the same question with three letter lists from THY with the same restrictions.  There are only $27$ unrestricted lists, so you can list them by hand.  There are 18 that don't start with T and 18 that don't end with Y, but clearly not 36 that either don't start with T or don't end with Y.  The problem is that there are 12 that both don't start with T and don't end with Y, so the final count is $18+18-12=24$  This is correct because there are only 3 that both start with T and end with Y and should not be counted.

Comment: for the original question, how would I go about calculating what the size of intersection of A and B are?

Comment: You need to compute the ones that both don't begin with T and don't end with Y.  So you have 5 choices for the first and last and 6 for each of the two middle ones.

Comment: @Wilson - intersection is things that don't start with a T and don't end in Y. So is 5.6.6.5

Comment: So does that give me a final answer of $|A \cup B| = 1080 + 1080 - 900 = 1260$?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 2):

We may simplify the problem by using De Morgan's laws:

\begin{align*}
  |A\cup B| &= \overline{\overline{|A\cup B|}} \\
  &= \overline{|\overline{A}\cap \overline{B}|} \\
  &= |U|-|\overline{A}\cap \overline{B}| \\
  &= 6^4-6^2 \\
  &= 1260
\end{align*}

Hence, for a $n$-letter list, the number of such lists is $6^n-6^{n-2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Seeking: **|A ∪ B| = |A| + |B| - |A ∩ B|**

**A**: 4-letter lists are there that don’t begin with T
$$5 \cdot 6^3 = 1080$$

**B**: 4-letter lists that don’t end in Y
$$6^3 \cdot 5 = 1080$$

**A ∩ B**: How many 4-letter lists are there that don’t begin with T AND don’t end in Y
$$5 \cdot 6 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 = 25 \cdot 36 = 900$$

So:
$$|A ∪ B| = 1080 + 1080 - 900 = 1260$$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thanks for the note, I'll look at that. I am coming over from Stack Overflow and happened to be working on the same problem so I just plopped in my answer.

Answer (score -2):

We can also calculate it like that:

We calculate the number of 4-letter lists without restrictions and from this number we subtract these one,which begin with T and  these,which end in Y.But subtracting the number of lists that begin with T and the number of lists that end in Y,we subtract twice the number of lists that begin with T AND end in Y,so wehave to add this number once.

So,it is:

$$6^4-1 \cdot 6 \cdot 6 \cdot 6 -6 \cdot 6 \cdot 6 \cdot 1+1 \cdot 6 \cdot 6 \cdot 1$$

If you have questions,feel free to ask..

Comment: The number of lists that begin with a T is $1.6.6.6$. This gets the wrong answer.....

Comment: Ok... you've fixed it now... but it is still logically equivalent to the OPs attempt at an answer, but doesn't give any indication as to why this works.... or why this is better than the OPs attempt (which I don't think it is). You should also reread your explanation because it doesn't correlate with the expression you've written.

Comment: Neither I think that it is better,I just wanted to tell an other way to approach the exercise.. :)

Comment: Ok.... but given that it's poorly worded (I think you mean "add the lists" instead of "subtract twice the lists") and has no explanation, I don't know what it adds

Comment: @Mathmo123 Is it better to now?

Comment: "we subtract twice the number of lists that begin with T AND end in Y."... is incorrect

Comment: This is not correct.  You have computed the number of sequences that neither start with T nor end with Y. You should only subtract those which both start with T and end with Y.